# Async function, do something after the map function is finished

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

```
async function testing(summoner_name) {
  try {
    var match;
    let summoner = {
      name: [summoner_name],
    };
    const id = await fetchAccountID(summoner_name);
    const matchList = await fetchMatches(id);
    Object.keys(matchList.matches).map((key, i) => {
      setTimeout(async function () {
        match = await fetchMatch(matchList.matches[key].gameId); 
        summoner = await getMatchStats(
          match,
          matchList.matches[key].champion,
          summoner
        );
      }, i * 100);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I would like to do something after the map function is done iterating over all the keys, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
async function testing(summoner_name) {
  try {
    let summoner = {
      name: [summoner_name],
    };
    const id = await fetchAccountID(summoner_name);
    const matchList = await fetchMatches(id);
    //Promise in Serial
    for (const key of Object.keys(matchList.matches)) {
      const match = await fetchMatch(matchList.matches[key].gameId);
      summoner = await getMatchStats(
        match,
        matchList.matches[key].champion,
        summoner
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```